# Tkinter SnakeGame пауза

Tags: python, tkinter

Добрый день нужна помощь. Делаю простую змейку, возникли проблемы с паузой. Удалось додуматься как ее поставить, но никак не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы пауза снималась той же кнопкой.

Код:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

GAME_WIDTH = 1000  # Game settings
GAME_HEIGHT = 600

SPEED = 80
SPACE_SIZE = 50
BODY_PARTS = 2

SNAKE_COLOR = "#00FF00"
FOOD_COLOR = "#FF0000"
BG_COLOR = "#000000"


class Snake:

    def __init__(self):
        self.body_size = BODY_PARTS
        self.coordinates = []
        self.squares = []

        for i in range(0, BODY_PARTS):
            self.coordinates.append([0, 0])

        for x, y in self.coordinates:
            square = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill=SNAKE_COLOR, tags='snake')
            self.squares.append(square)


class Food:

    def __init__(self):
        x = random.randint(0, (GAME_WIDTH / SPACE_SIZE - 1)) * SPACE_SIZE
        y = random.randint(0, (GAME_HEIGHT / SPACE_SIZE - 1)) * SPACE_SIZE

        self.coordinates = [x, y]

        canvas.create_oval(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill=FOOD_COLOR, tag="food")


def next_turn(snake, food):
    global stop

    if not stop:
        rb.pack_forget()

        x, y = snake.coordinates[0]

        if direction == "up":
            y -= SPACE_SIZE
        elif direction == "down":
            y += SPACE_SIZE
        elif direction == "left":
            x -= SPACE_SIZE
        elif direction == "right":
            x += SPACE_SIZE

        snake.coordinates.insert(0, (x, y))

        square = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill=SNAKE_COLOR)

        snake.squares.insert(0, square)

        if x == food.coordinates[0] and y == food.coordinates[1]:
            global score, best_score
            score += 1  # After eat food score + 1
            label.config(text="Score: {}".format(score))

            canvas.delete("food")

            food = Food()

            if score > best_score:  # Best score
                best_score = score

        else:
            del snake.coordinates[-1]
            canvas.delete(snake.squares[-1])

            del snake.squares[-1]

        if check_collisions(snake):
            game_over()

        else:
            window.after(SPEED, next_turn, snake, food)

    elif stop:
        canvas.create_text(canvas.winfo_width() / 2, canvas.winfo_height() / 3, font=('consolas', 50), text='PAUSE',
                           fill='#ffffff')


def change_direction(new_direction):  # Changing snake direction with binding keys for moving

    global direction

    if new_direction == 'left':
        if direction != 'right':
            direction = new_direction
    elif new_direction == 'right':
        if direction != 'left':
            direction = new_direction
    elif new_direction == 'up':
        if direction != 'down':
            direction = new_direction
    elif new_direction == 'down':
        if direction != 'up':
            direction = new_direction


def check_collisions(snake):
    x, y = snake.coordinates[0]

    if x < 0 or x >= GAME_WIDTH:
        return True
    elif y < 0 or y >= GAME_HEIGHT:
        return True

    for body_part in snake.coordinates[1:]:
        if x == body_part[0] and y == body_part[1]:
            return True

    return False


def game_over():
    rb.pack()
    canvas.delete(ALL)
    canvas.create_text(canvas.winfo_width() / 2, canvas.winfo_height() / 3, font=('consolas', 50), text='GAME OVER',
                       fill='#ffffff')

    canvas.create_text(canvas.winfo_width() / 2, canvas.winfo_height() / 2, font=('consolas', 30),
                       text=f'Best Score: {best_score}', fill='#ffffff')


def restart_game():
    global snake, food, score, direction

    canvas.delete(ALL)
    snake = Snake()
    food = Food()
    score = 0
    direction = 'down'

    label.config(text="Score: {}".format(score))

    next_turn(snake, food)


def pause(event):                               # Pause function

    global stop
    stop = True


window = Tk()  # Window settings
window.title("Snake game")
window.resizable(False, False)


direction = 'down'  # Snake direction


stop = False                 # Game pause
window.bind('<space>', pause)


score = 0  # Score
best_score = 0

label = Label(window, text="Score: {}".format(score), activebackground='white', font=('consolas', 40))
label.pack()

canvas = Canvas(window, bg=BG_COLOR, height=GAME_HEIGHT, width=GAME_WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

rb = Button(window, text='Restart', command=restart_game, font=('consolas', 20))  # Restart Button
rb.place(x=GAME_WIDTH / 2, y=700)
rb.pack()

window.update()  # window update
window_width = window.winfo_width()
window_height = window.winfo_height()
screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()

x = int((screen_width / 2) - (window_width / 2))
y = int((screen_height / 2) - (window_height / 2))

window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (window_width, window_height, x, y))

window.bind('<Left>', lambda event: change_direction('left'))  # Bind Keys for moving snake
window.bind('<Right>', lambda event: change_direction('right'))
window.bind('<Up>', lambda event: change_direction('up'))
window.bind('<Down>', lambda event: change_direction('down'))

snake = Snake()
food = Food()

next_turn(snake, food)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Храните где-то текущее состояние игры. В обработчике нажатия на кнопку проверяете: если игра не на паузе, ставите на паузу, если уже на паузе - снимаете паузу.

Comment: @insolor, Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ. Получилось сделать нужную функцию, позже ее доработаю. Но появился странный "баг"(но я все же думаю, что это моя ошибка), после снятия паузы "змейка" не реагирует на "еду". Очень редко, после быстрого нажимания на паузу она все таки ее съедает, но делает это немного странно. Могу я спросить у Вас с чем это связано? Если можно, то я прикреплю код.

Comment: "Могу я спросить у Вас с чем это связано?" - гаданием по фотографии не занимаюсь

Comment: @insolor , Очень жаль, хаха. В любом случае - спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Для такого можно завести переменную с числовым значением, т. е. 0 или 1. Для этого подойдет тот же самый *stop*. Затем создать функцию pause_play, в которой поставить условие:

```
if stop == 0:
    stop = 1
else:
    stop = 0
```

И забиндить эту функцию на какую-либо клавишу так же, как вы забиндили повороты на стрелочки.
Надеюсь помог!
P. S. Я не увидел объяснения в комментариях, сильно извиняюсь, если кто-либо подумал, что я украл это решение.